# Python Regex for selecting lines that follows a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

How can I make a regex that will select lines that does not follow a pattern.
So I have log file that has the following pattern:

[12.12.2022 22:26:25] <01> Info             Unregistering TCP client channel [bstcp]
[12.12.2022 22:26:25] <01> Info             Channel successfully unregistered

but everytime a new log starts it will also log the following:

===================================================================
Starting new log
Process: [64 bit], PID: [5028], SessionId: [0]

How can I select only the ones with the patter:

[date]  loglevel message

Thanks

I was trying things on https://regex101.com/ but I was not successful.

I am expecting to select all the lines that has the following pattern:

[date]  loglevel message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want lines starting with the date/timestamp, you should be able to just use the following regex pattern in multiline mode:

```
^\[\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\].*$
```

The date pattern is fairly distinct and should only match the lines you want.

### Demo